# Хром ругается на небезопасное соединение

Tags: apache, google-chrome, denwer, https, localhost

В качестве локального сервера использую Denwer apache 2.2.22 Firefox и IE грузят с localhost без происшествий, а вот Хром ругается на сертификат и выводит следующее:

> lineage.loc использует недействительный сертификат безопасности. К сертификату нет доверия, так как он является самоподписанным. Сертификат недействителен для любого имени сервера. (Код ошибки: sec_error_unknown_issuer)

Хром блокирует загрузку внешних скриптов и библиотек вот сообщения консоли:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://lineage.loc/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow&v1&subset=latin,cyrillic'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
lineage.loc/:12 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://lineage.loc/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300&v2&subset=latin,cyrillic'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
lineage.loc/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://lineage.loc/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
lineage.loc/:88 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://lineage.loc/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www6.cbox.ws/box/?boxid=332607&boxtag=5e2htn&sec=main'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
lineage.loc/:96 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://lineage.loc/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www6.cbox.ws/box/?boxid=332607&boxtag=5e2htn&sec=form'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
lineage.loc/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://lineage.loc/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
jquery.easing.1.3.js:39 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
jquery.mousewheel.js:78 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
jquery.vaccordion.js:415 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
lineage.loc/:263 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
lineage.loc/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://lineage.loc/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure plugin resource 'http://mans2.jimdo.com/s/swf/1726664116.swf?1246950742'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Как исправить?

Comment: А что за хост такой `lineage.loc`?

Comment: @gil9red алиас локалхоста, я полагаю. Для разработки.

Comment: Почему просто не localhost?

Comment: Поройтесь в настройках Хрома

Comment: localhost открывает страницу денвера. Проекты помещаются по следующей иерархии denwer/home/название проекта/www/файлы и папки проекта.

    например: denwer/home/mysite.loc/www/index.html
   
 далее для доступа в адресной строке:
   ` http://mysite.loc`

Comment: Более концептуальный вопрос: если это домен для разработки, то зачем его вообще пытаться открывать по HTTPS?

Answer (score 7):

Прежде всего если у вас хттпс все то все ссылки должны быть HTTPS://. . .  если не знаете то можно указывать //. . .  и хттпс или хттп определит сам браузер.

А то, что ругается только хром на сертификат, так может приобрести нормальный сертификат, и не ждать когда клюнет жареный петух. Потому как пользователи будут заходить с разных браузеров, и у кого-то вообще может заблочить ваш сайт.

Answer (score 6):

Это называется Mixed Content, все ссылки на станице должны быть с https или с //, которая тоже явно ведёт на https.

Comment: Можете посоветовать ресурс где можно узнать о _Это называется Mixed Content, все ссылки на станице должны быть......_

Comment: Пожалуйста, https://www.emaro-ssl.ru/blog/smeshannoe-soderzhimoe-https/

Comment: странно, мой пост раньше и шире отвечает на вопрос.... но видимо задающему виднее...

Comment: @VladimirCh не переживай. Хочешь плюсик поставлю?

Comment: не переживаю, просто часто встречал с другими, ответов несколько, решений несколько а ответ только один ! Атеперь сам столкнулся и интерестно! А за то, чтобы подымать верный ответ - я всегда за :)

Answer (score 2):

Так как вам надо для отладки, возможно стоит просто стартовать Chrome в спец режиме, но имейте в виду что у драгих пользователей клиентов все равно будут аналогичные проблемы

```
--ignore-certificate-errors
```

Comment: _но имейте в виду что у драгих пользователей клиентов все равно будут аналогичные проблемы........_ Как избежать этого?

Comment: Сделать нормальный hostname c DNS, сделать сертификат - например есть StartSSL бесплатный (https://www.startssl.com/Support?v=1)

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте  Ваш сертификат:

1. Настройки-> внизу "Показать дополнительные настройки"
2. HTTPS/SSL-> настроить сертификаты.
3. Ищем сгенирированный сертфикат. Если не находим добавляем.